# Undefined offset: 0 Codeigniter

Tags: php

```
function chart($id){
    $rows = array(); $rows2 = array();
        $data['mikrotik'] = $this->mikrotik_api->interfaces()->ethernet()->get_byname($id);
    if(count(isset($data[0])) > 0 ){
        $rx = number_format($data[0]["rx-bits-per-second"]/1024,1);
        $tx = number_format($data[0]["tx-bits-per-second"]/1024,1);
        $rows['name'] = 'Tx';
        $rows['data'][] = $tx;
        $rows2['name'] = 'Rx';
        $rows2['data'][] = $rx;
    }
    else{
        echo "<font color='#ff0000'>Koneksi gagal</font>";
    }

$result = array();
array_push($result,$rows);
array_push($result,$rows2);
print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}
```

I've got undefined index 0 in $rx and $tx variable , may be someone can check what's wrong with the code

Comment: check what is inside `$data[0]` because it is causing the undefined index 0

Comment: Debug 101 - See what is happening.... So we want to view what $data looks like... You can use var_dump($data) or print_r ($data) after $data['mikrotik'] statement and show your output.

Comment: when i did as you say , output show array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "!trap" [1]=> string(26) "=message=unknown parameter" [2]=> string(5) "!done" }

Comment: public function get_byname($id){
        $input = array(
            'command' => '/interface/monitor-traffic',
            'id' => $id
        );
        return $this->query($input);
    }

Answer (score 1):

From your updated question (thanks for that), the output for $data['mikrotik'] is

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "!trap" [1]=> string(26) "=message=unknown parameter" [2]=> string(5) "!done" }
```

Which is way off the mark of what you are expecting... So there is an error occurring.

Your statement to try to indentify if you have valid data is "interesting".

```
if(count(isset($data[0])) > 0 )
```

This does not make any sense.

`isset($data[0])` will return True or False. Then you are performing a count on it, so count( true or false ) will always be > 0.
`count()` is expecting an array, not a Boolean!

A "suggestion" would be to change that to

```
if(isset($data[0]))
```

So from your output, you are getting some kind of error which you need to investigate AND it's a different question to this one. If you have to, create a new question to deal with it.